# iPhone 5's low light boost mode

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

Has anyone been able to get the iPhone 5's new low light boost mode to work in their custom camera app? I tried the following code, but noticed no difference - whereas the native camera app significantly boosted the brightness.

```
if ([[captureManager backFacingCamera] isLowLightBoostEnabled]) {

    [[captureManager backFacingCamera] automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `lockForConfiguration`, according to the docs (well, the header file):

```
if ([[self backFacingCamera] respondsToSelector:@selector(isLowLightBoostSupported)]) {
  if ([[self backFacingCamera] lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
    if ([self backFacingCamera].isLowLightBoostSupported)
      [self backFacingCamera].automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable = YES;
    [[self backFacingCamera] unlockForConfiguration];
  }
}
```

Also, `isLowLightBoostEnabled` tells you whether or not the low light is actually being boosted, not whether it can be. That's the `isLowLightBoostSupported` selector, as above (to which only iOS 6 devices respond).

Comment: Got it working after I changed your `respondsToSelector` if statement to `isLowLightBoostSupported`. Thanks!

Comment: Has anyone observed whether isLowLightBoostEnabled is ever getting true? 
I do not manage to do so on IOS 7.3 with an iPhone 5 even if I wrap the phone in a blanket.

Comment: Yes. If .isLowLightBoostSupported and .automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable = YES, then I have no problem with if ([[device] isLowLightBoostEnabled]) reading correctly.