# iPhone 5S lowLightBoost seems not supported. Why?

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I'm trying to add lowLightBoost, but on the iPhone i'm testing it is not supported. Am I doing something wrong or did Apple block this feature on iPhone 5S ?

I can paste code for AVCaptureSession's setup if necessary, but it's just basic, taken from some example. I'm not doing anything fancy now...

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 5's low light boost mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674917/iphone-5s-low-light-boost-mode)

Comment: not a duplicate, please note the apostrophe and the date of question

Comment: The other question came before yours, and is asking the same thing.  Both questions are essentially "The lightboost feature isn't working.  How do I get it to work?"  The other question is more descriptive than yours (it details exactly how his code didn't work, and he posts the code he is using).  It also has a good answer that should answer your question.  If your question is fundamentally different and that answer does not help, then please update your question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone 5S simply does not support low light boost mode. I'd guess that with the improvements made to the camera/sensor on the 5S, that Apple decided the low light boost mode was not necessary on that device.

I posted a similar answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562076/234609

Comment: Apple's decisions are strange, but native Camera.app supports low light boost (I can see the difference). And couple other apps seem to be able to use this functionality also... Not sure how, though ;)